# Fullcalendar time-Grid - column weeks

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Here is what I'm looking to build:[image: Monday of week as the column header, and a range of times for the rows]

I've found that Fullcalendar can show this exact type of presentation for an **individual week** where each column represents a day of that week. Here is a screenshot of that:

[image: FullCalendar Timegrid]

What I'm looking for is the ability to view an entire week as a column (exactly like the first image portrays). In my use-case, an event spans several weeks at the same time-slot - and for a planning calendar, this view is essential for my users. FullCalendar doesn't seem to give granular control over the columns in the timegrid plugin specifically.  What I'm wondering is if this can be achieved using some other plugin or technique, or if there's something I haven't found in the documentation that makes this doable.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `In my use-case, an event spans several weeks at the same time-slot`...in fullCalendar this is implemented as a recurring event. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events

Comment: P.s. I don't see any material difference between your two screenshots. Unclear what you mean by `view an entire week as a column`...in the first screenshot, each day is clearly in a separate column.

Comment: @ADyson each column represents a week that begins on a Monday (6/29/2020, 7/6/2020, etc).   Even though there is a date in the header, it represents a week beginning on that day.  To your point, for clarity, it should read "06/29 - 07/05" in the header.

Comment: Also @ADyson - as I understand "recurring events" - it represents an event that spans multiple days, but not a rendering of the calendar in my "zoomed out" view of weeks.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, sorry. No you can't do that with fullCalendar, not without building a custom view anyway - I imagine you could adapt the timeGrid code into a new view type in order to do it, but it would require new code, it can't be done through config alone. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js (and maybe also https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features and https://fullcalendar.io/contributing